# Modify the Householder reflector so that it works for a vector with complex entries

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Explain how to modify the definition of the Householder reflector so that it works
for a vector with complex entries. That is, given $x \in \mathbb C^m$ , how should be define the
unit vector $v$ so that $(I_d−2vv^*)x = \|x\|e_1$?

I know $\mathbb C^m$ is an actually 2m dimensional space, so how to modify the above formula in order to suit for $\mathbb C^m$ case?

Answer (score 4):

The modification goes as follows
\begin{align}
\hat{u} &= \frac{x + e^{i\theta} ||x||e_1}{||x + e^{i\theta} ||x||e_1||}, \\
H &= -e^{-i\theta}(I - 2 \hat{u} \hat{u}^*),
\end{align}
where $x_1=e^{i\theta}|x_1|$.

In this case, you have $Hx = ||x|| e_1$.

See https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0609050.pdf at page 19 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed in lots of textbooks on numerical linear algebra.  See for example:

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/rvdg/books/HQR.pdf

Comment: The material that you provided works for real vector but I want an answer for complex vector.

Comment: This will work in the complex case as well.  Keep in mind that for complex $z$, $\mbox{sign}(z)=z/|z|$.

Comment: I'm thinking about a whole day but don't understand what you said. Can you add more details？

Comment: I'm afraid that you're going to have to work through the calculations- try it on a random example and see what happens.